# How can I send a pdf created by my app to another app through URI scheme in Android?

Tags: android, pdf, printing

I have been trying to send some data from one app to the other through my app. The app to which I send the data is a printer based app(Star PassPRNT app) and the only way I could find to interact and send data to it was through a URI scheme.

[Here](http://www.starmicronics.com/support/ZipFile.aspx?sat2=246&id=246&type=4&referrer=http://www.starmicronics.com/support/sdkdocumentation.aspx&tabText) is the documentation for the android version.

**The problem** I am facing is that I have to send the app a PDF document through the URI scheme only, and I can't find relevant information about it anywhere on the web. I am new so I must have missed something.

Also, if this is not possible, please guide me as to how I can send a HTML document with text and images from my app through the same URI scheme by changing the pdf query to html query.

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri.fromFile(new File("YOUR_PDF_PATH.pdf")
```

and to do the same with your HTML file:

```
Uri.fromFile(new File("YOUR_HTML_PATH.html")
```

Comment: but how would I link this URI with the URI I use to start their App? Anyways I just found a solution, which was to encode the Pdf file to Base64 binary and then pass it, it seemed to work.

Comment: I dont know how you could start their app, using Intent maybe? How are you passing the Base64 binary?